# Using qconf to change reporting_params

Tags: sungridengine, qsub

How do I use `qconf` to change the values of `reporting_params`?

`qconf  -mconf` Looks like what I want but that opens an editor which I would like to avoid doing.

Comment: After seeing answer by @William Hay, clearly my answer is wrong, and applies to only queue configuration. I'll leave my answer here for those that want to modify queue config.

Answer (score 3):

`qconf -sconf > File`

modify the file however you prefer.

`qconf -Mconf File`

In general upper case -M... or -A... switches will work with a file while lower case (-m... -a... ) variants drop you in an editor.

You could also set the EDITOR environment variable to point to a script that modifies the file in the way you want and updates its modification time before calling qconf -mconf.

Answer (score 0):

According to `man qconf` you can list configuration and dump to file:

```
qconf -sq short.q > short.q
```

Modify the file, then load config back:

```
qconf -Mq short.q
```

There are other ways to do this, as specified in `man qconf`.

Comment: After seeing answer by @William Hay, clearly my answer is wrong, and applies to only queue configuration. I'll leave my answer here for those that want to modify queue config.